# Selenium Copy & Paste from PDF to System Clipboard

Tags: java, selenium, clipboard, copy-paste

We have a PDF link that opens in browser via the chrome built in PDF viewer. We are trying to verify the text in this PDF, without using PDFBox or downloading the file to our local system.

Our attempt uses `Keys.chord` to send "CTRL+A" and "CTRL+C" (both upper and lower case versions) to the browser. (This results in a big blue box selection rather than the line selection we see when trying copy paste manually). We think that there are sufficient delays of 2 seconds between the commands, yet the text content doesn't show up in the system clipboard (tested via pasting to notepad). Should we be sending these actions to a specific web element rather than "body" or "html"?

Additionally, when we try to use the [`Clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) we get an unsupported flavor unicode string exception.

Any insight into copy pasting from the built in chrome pdf viewer via selenium would be appreciated.

```
// This results in a weird blue selection box
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "A");
webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectAll);

Thread.sleep(2000);

String copyAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "C");
webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(copyAll);

Thread.sleep(2000);

// Error happens here
String result = Toolkit.getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Comment: can you share here your code trials?

Comment: @Prophet updated with some example code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `a` instead if `A`

```
WebElement ele = webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
ele.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));

Thread.sleep(2000);
```

similarly `c` instead of `C`

```
ele.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "c"));
Thread.sleep(2000);

String result = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Comment: We tried with lower case already, and it didn't work.

Comment: this wasn't updated in the OP.

Comment: Sorry, we just tried with your solution.